# How to create many pages with the same content except for one variable?

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, multilingual

I have over 100 pages to create and they will have the same exact content except for one variable (dog breed).

Examples:

- `www.dog.com/husky-dog`
- `www.dog.com/rottweiler-dog`
- `www.dog.com/pitbull-dog`
  and so on...

All of the pages have the same module (where the dog breed variable field is located).

I would like to know what's the best way to create that many pages without having to create one article, one menu item and one module association for each of them.

Note that my site is multilingual so the manual process is even longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple administration method would be

- Install Regular Labs' Add To Menu plugin
- After saving the first article, click the **Add To menu** button and quickly add
- Next, do **Save as copy** and change the title and alias
- Do the Add to menu again
- Repeat steps 3 and 4

Other quite tedious and possible confusing method is to prepare a .sql file and write the INSERT values for the __content table with the same introtext and change the other necessary columns

Then write INSERTS for the __menu table

Then import the file via your db manager.

See the add to menu plugin at [Regular Labs add to menu plugin](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/add-to-menu/)

Comment: If you are going to do this then create the first article and use the bulk copy option. Keep selecting all and doing bulk copy. Soon enough you'll have enough selected to make many articles.  You can change the number of articles shown on screen to increase the amount.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can batch menus too but you'll have to check.

Comment: @Eoin the work required after batch copies will equate to the same, being that all the copied article titles and aliases will need to be changed individually, and the menu items created by the add to menu ext does not respond to batch copy so no menu item will exist for the copies.

Comment: Yes, I suppose so, fair point.

Answer (score 3):

Check the JED for any suitable Mass Content extensions which can help with uploading bulk articles and menu options: https://extensions.joomla.org/tags/mass-content

For example, I have used [OSContent](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/oscontent) previously which can create articles and menu options 10 at a time.

There are some other extensions where you can enter your content into a spreadsheet and then import it into Joomla.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would make the first one. Then download the database file from PHPMyAdmin as a CSV file. If you want you can only export the relevant tables for ease.

Then I would use Excel or Google Sheets to open it.  Then I would find the relevant tables for the article and menus.

Then I'd copy and paste them and make them this way.

Finally, drop the original tables and reupload the relevant ones. Usually I make sure the fields are intact before importing.

I think that's the quickest way and you don't need to know SQL.